# I'm curious about what a line of code does when using Object Oriented Programming with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, user-interface, tkinter

I was trying to create an application using Tkinter and I thought about doing it Object Oriented style. As I was reading through the code I was using as reference, I saw a line of code that got me confused. This is a sample of the code:

```
class GUI:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

        root.title('PyTube Program')
        
        self.menu_bar = tk.Menu(root)
        self.menu_bar.add_command(label='About', command=self.show_about)

        root.configure(menu=self.menu_bar)


    def show_about():
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    # -----
    main_window = GUI(root)
    # -----

    root.resizable(0, 0)
    root.mainloop()
```

I do not understand what the line `main_window = GUI(root)` does (That's how it was in the reference code).

I was thinking that it was a form of class inheritance but if that was so, shouldn't the main loop line of code be `main_window.mainloop()` not `root.mainloop()`?

Because when I tried that, the method wasn't recognized. Also when I remove the `main_window = GUI(root)` line of code, nothing appears on the GUI.

I apologize if this question is not clear.

Comment: It creates an object (instance) of class `GUI`. You should work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: consider accepting my answer if your question is resolved, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more wise to rely on sample code from the official Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html). There is also an sample for OOP.

There are two options:

1. You can inherit from the Frame class `class GUI(tk.Frame)` and then these lines

```py
    root = tk.Tk()
    main_window = GUI(root)
    main_window.mainloop()
```

make perfect sense as you ceate an Tk instance called root and then assing it the frame main_window.

2. You can inherit directly from the TK class `class GUI(tk.TK)` in which case you can delete the declaration `root = tk.Tk()` which is now the class itself (self).

In both cases you have to **init** the class you inherit from like this `super().__init__(master)`. In your case the class could look like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('PyTube Program')
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.menu_bar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.menu_bar.add_command(label='About', command=self.show_about)
        self.configure(menu=self.menu_bar)

    def show_about(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_window = GUI()
    main_window.mainloop()
```